# Loss is very erratic in the 100s and val_loss is at 0, something - what is the reason for that?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, convolutional-neural-network, mlp

I have a problem. I would like to solve a NLP classification problem.
For this I have trained a CNN and since I have other features, I wanted to include them in the model training.
Thus I have concatenated a CNN and the other features.

However, the problem is that the `loss` jumps to `175,10,100.8,...` . The `val_loss`, on the other hand, is at `0, something`.
What is the reason that the `loss` is so high and erratic?

Is it because the features and CNN cannot interpret the model correctly? Should the features be trained by a standalone model first?

What is the reason that the model has such an erratic `loss`? And what does that tell us?

[image]

[image]

```py
class CNN_1D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def forward(self):
            # filter_sizes = [1,2,3,5]
            # num_filters = 32
            extra_nb_features = df_train.shape[1]

            inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
            extra_inp = Input(shape=(extra_nb_features, ))

            x = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
            x = SpatialDropout1D(0.4)(x)
            # x = Reshape((maxlen, embed_size, 1))(x)

            x = Conv1D(256, 7, activation='relu')(x)
            x = MaxPooling1D()(x)
            
            
            x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu")(x)
            x = MaxPooling1D()(x)
            
            x = Dropout(0.2)(x)  
            #x = Flatten()(x)
            x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
            combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, extra_inp])

            combined = Dropout(0.15)(combined)
            
            outp = Dense(128, activation="relu")(combined)

            outp = Dense(numbmer, activation="softmax")(outp)

            model = Model(inputs=[inp, extra_inp] , outputs=outp)
            model.summary()
            return model
```

Comment: Are you sure the accuracy graph is correctly labelled? Because the val accuracy is higher than training accuracy, this is definitely not normal. If the graph is correct, I don't even know what can cause this but I would guess something is wrong in the data. What is the size of the data? Number of instances by class? Also I'd suggest starting with a traditional method like decision tree: this would give you a baseline perf and you could check more easily if the data/evaluation part works correctly.

Comment: Very small batch_size can cause this. Also, add your pre-processing steps and model training parms.